# ROS co-ordinate system for orientation

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I know through reading http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html that the ROS co-ordinate frame follows the right hand rule.  So when getting transformation data from a VR device I have to convert:

x= -z,
y=-x,
z= y

I've managed to map movements of positions correctly, however I'm having trouble with rotations...
I tried doing the same mapping for for rotations & it doesn't seem to work.   Is there another rule I have to adhere to or another conversion I can do to get correct mapping for orientation (roll, pitch, yaw)? or perhaps a way to find the correct mapping..?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298476/ros-co-ordinate-system-for-orientation/) by [flightlesskite](https://answers.ros.org/users/36259/flightlesskite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-07-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-07-24**:\

1. What are you trying to do? 2) Did you check this? https://answers.unity.com/storage/temp/12048-lefthandedtorighthanded.pdf

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-07-24**:
Can you provide more info on what your setup looks like? What information is your device reporting (e.g., position, velocity, orientation, acceleration, angular vel)?

**Comment by [flightlesskite](https://answers.ros.org/users/36259/flightlesskite/) on 2018-07-25**:
Hi, I'm trying to map HTC controllers to a Baxter robot through ROS to achieve teleoperation.  Right now, I believe I have got the position (x, y ,z) mapped correctly using the right hand rule, but struggling with orientation now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. You can convert any left-handed coordinate system to right-handed by flipping the sign of one of its axes. [1] By changing more axes, you are rotating the coordinate system.
2. A quaternion (x, y, z, w) in a left-handed coordinate system (x,y,z) should simply become (x, y, -z, w) in a right-handed coordinate system (x, y, -z). Please try it out and report back.

Sources:
[1] Section 3.1. in https://answers.unity.com/storage/temp/12048-lefthandedtorighthanded.pdf
[2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673777/convert-quaternion-from-right-handed-to-left-handed-coordinate-system
[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion
[4] Reasoning for the second part of this answer: https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2018-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0